# JSON Response {"d":"128.00"} but displaying "128"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have been working on a shopping cart that the user can add/remove order items as they please and am returning an updated sub-total via a webservice using jQuery $.ajax

Here is how I am calling the webservice and setting the sub-total with the response.

```
//perform the ajax call
$.ajax({
    url: p,
    data: '{' + s + '}',
    success: function(sTotal) {
        //order was updated: set span to new sub-total
        $("#cartRow" + orderID).find(".subTotal").text(sTotal);
    },
    failure: function() {
        //if the orer was not saved

        //console.log('Error: Order not deleted');
    }
});
```

The response I am getting seems perfectly fine:

```
{"d":"128.00"}
```

When I display the total on the page it displays as 128 rather than 128.00

I am fully sure it is something very simple and silly but I am so deep into it now I need someone with a fresh brain to help me out!!

Cheers :)

EDIT

I am also using $.ajaxSetup to set the correct contentType:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: "{}",
dataFilter: function(data) {
    var msg;

    if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function')
        msg = JSON.parse(data);
    else
        msg = eval('(' + data + ')');

    if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
        return msg.d;
    else
        return msg;
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I don't see anywhere in this code where you access the `d` property of the response.</strike>

Perhaps you mean to do this?

```
$("#cartRow" + orderID).find(".subTotal").text(sTotal.d);
// --------------------------------------------------^^
```

### EDIT

Ok, I see the problem.  You're returning JSON but not defining a **dataType** in the `$.ajax()` call.  This means that jQuery sees your `application/json` mimetype and interprets the response as JSON.  `128.00` in JSON is a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number), not a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String).  However, `"128.00"` would be a String.

In order to keep this working, You need to format the response before printing it (as others have suggested), or adjust your endpoint to return a valid JSON *string*.

Here's my test to prove the solution

```
<div id="test">
  Subtotal <span class="subTotal"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php',
  data: {},
  success: function(sTotal) {
    //order was updated: set span to new sub-total
    $("#test").find(".subTotal").text(sTotal);
  }
});

</script>
```

and test.php

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
echo '128.00';
```

Output

> Subtotal 128

But when I change **test.php** to be this

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
echo '"128.00"';
```

The expected output is generated

> Subtotal 128.00

Or, you could alternatively tell jQuery to treat the response as text by specifying a **dataType** parameter, for example

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php',
  data: {},
  dataType: 'text',  // <---- here
  success: function(sTotal) {
    //order was updated: set span to new sub-total
    $("#test").find(".subTotal").text(sTotal);
  }
});
```

### EDIT 2

Ok, after messing with this some more, I see what's going on.  The **dataFilter** handler you defined converts the response into JSON itself, and in this case, returns the string `128.00`. *However*, jQuery *still applies* the intellgent-guessed dataType (which is JSON) to this value before sending it to the success handler.

There are a multitude of ways to fix this, all of which depend on what other AJAX calls your application relies on this setup for. The quick-fix I applied in my test was to do this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: "{}",
  // define the text data type so that we return data.d, jQuery doesn't parse it as JSON again
  dataType: 'text',
  dataFilter: function(data) {
      data = $.parseJSON( data ); // Use jQuery's parsing
      if (data.hasOwnProperty('d'))
      {
          return data.d;
      }else{
          return data;
      }
  }
});
```

But that may not work across the board for you

Comment: 'd' is used by ASP.NET AJAX to wrap the returned value.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention I am using ASP.NET AJAX!

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help. I updated my queston above to show how I am using jQuery.ajaxSetup() to set the correct content type. I must admit, I am a little lost!

Answer (score 2):

That is because the value is treated as a number, while you want it treated as a string.
When you are using '.. .text(sTotal)', you are actually calling the .toString() method on the Number object wrapping the primitive sTotal. And since this is a whole number, it displays it without decimals.
You need to use a format the number as a string prior to calling .text(foo) for the number to be formatted like that.

This will give you two decimals

```
var a=1/3; 
a = a.toString(); 
switch(a.lastIndexOf(".")){ 
    case -1: 
        a+=".00";
        break; 
    case a.length-2: 
        a+="0"; 
        break; 
    default: 
        a=a.substring(0, a.indexOf(".") + 3); 
} 
alert(a);
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? I assume its not just:

var totalString = msg.toString();
            
            $("#cartRow" + orderID).find(".subTotal").text(totalString);

Comment: This is will give you two decimals
<pre><code>

    var a=1/3;
    a = a.toString();
    switch(a.lastIndexOf(".")){
        case -1:
            a+=".00"
            break;
        case a.length-2:
            a+="0";
            break;
        default:
            a=a.substring(0, a.indexOf(".") + 3);
    }
    alert(a);
</code></pre>

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 $("#cartRow" + orderID).find(".subTotal").text(sTotal.toFixed(2));
```

HTH

Comment: Thats wierd...I tried it in JSFiddle and it worked perfect. Please check if you are doing a parseInt or parseFloat while loading the value to .subTotal through some other event. HTH

Comment: That was it! Wow, thanks man. I am letting a huge sigh of relief out as we speak..